# turning hash key (unsigned long) to int safely

Tags: c, hash, hashcode

I have a hash function:

```
 unsigned long strhash(char *string)
  {   
     unsigned long hash = 5381;
     int c;

     while (c = *string++)
        {   
           hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;
        }   
     return hash;
  }
```

and my program calls it like so

```
char testString[] = "Hello World";
unsigned long hashcode = 0;
hashcode = strhash(testString);
int slot = 0;
slot = hashcode%30;

printf("%d\n", slot);
```

the module is to module what will be the size of my array
is this safely converting from unsigned long to int?
because it prints out 17 making me feel like it is working but I am unsure

Comment: Why not make slot unsigned, too? Having a negative slot / index makes little sense to me. (BTW: what is tmp ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I assume you meant `printf("%d\n", slot);` in the last statement.

By doing a modulo with 30, you are effectively restricting the hash value to only 30 unique values (0 to 29). This drastically reduces the effectiveness of the hash, as many different strings will be mapped to the same hash value (one out of those 30).

This [link](http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx) gives you a number of alternative hash functions, including an unsigned int version of the `djb2` algorithm in your question. Use one of them instead.